# Must $A$ or $B$ be compact if $AB$ is compact?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space $H$. Suppose $AB$ is compact.

> Must $A$ or $B$ be compact?

I suppose that the answer is "no", but I cannot find any counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find an example where $A$ and $B$ are infinite-dimensional projections (and thus not compact) but $AB = 0$.

Comment: sweet !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Elegant example.

Comment: Thank you! It is a really nice example)